# how to make condition query selection

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
|               category table             |
--------------------------------------------
id   |  name |
--------------------------------------------
1    |  book    |   --->1 digit is a category
11   |  aa      |   --->2 digit is a sub category
2    |  software|
21   |  ba      |
22   |  bb      |
23   |  bc      |
```

I want the output like this:

```
---------------------------------
sub_id  |name_sub |name_category
---------------------------------
11      |aa       |book
21      |ba       |software
22      |bb       |software
23      |bc       |software
```

select all sub ID(2 digits), sub id names, and category name(1 digit from the left)

Comment: In general, this is a malformed table setup. If you want to distinguish between between category and sub-category, then define 2 columns. That makes live much easier for future extensions (and they will come).

Comment: I copied the database model from this https://github.com/Rizki36/wilayah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Wiimm` already mentioned in the comments, this looks very pointless to me for obvious reasons, but if your categories are going to remain 2 digit IDs with parent always having a single digit, below query would work using simple math divison operation.

```
select c1.id as sub_id,c1.name as name_sub ,c2.name as name_category
from category c1
inner join category c2
on cast((c1.id / 10) as UNSIGNED) = c2.id
```

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qmbYDxpDLvnzUDZ9AU4kTH/0

Comment: this code works well in my browser, but an error in my project

Comment: output is wrong,
number 10 function for what?(c1.id / **10**)

Comment: @RizkiFitra What's the output you are getting? It's work fine in the demo I attached too.

Comment: Yes, it works well, but I only need to use self join, thank you

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data, it looks like this might be an acceptable shortcut:

```
SELECT id sub_id, name name_sub, LEFT(name, 1) name_category
FROM category
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(id) = 2
```

Otherwise, you can also use a JOIN:

```
SELECT c1.id sub_id, c1.name name_sub, c2.name name_category
FROM category c1
INNER JOIN category c2 ON c2.id = LEFT(c1.id, 1)
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(c1.id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `correlated subquery`

```
select id,
       name as name_sub,
       ( select substring(name,1,1) from tab where id=t.id ) 
       as name_category
  from tab t
 where length(name)=2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/XCMQ54554)</kbd>

Comment: can the name of the table be separated (tab t)?

Comment: @RizkiFitra yes, that's an alias which reperesents the table.

Comment: @RizkiFitra not problem :)